# XML and XMLList and XMLListCollection in Flex 3

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

Please explain me what is the difference between XML and XMLList and XMLListCollection. If possible in simple words with example. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, links to Flex 3 Language Reference - a must have bookmark for looking this stuff up.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/index.html

[XML](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/XML.html)

[XMLList](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/XMLList.html)

[XMLListCollection](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/collections/XMLListCollection.html)

Secondly, I'd say check the `Examples` link for XMLList as that gives a good working example between the difference of XML and XMLList.

Use XML when you want to create a variable with a value of an XML document.

```
var mybooks:XML = <books>
  <book>
    <title>Book1</title>
  </book>
  <book>
     <title>Book2</title>
  </book>
</books>;
```

Use XMLList to create subsets of data from an XML variable.

```
var mybookTitles:XMLList = mybooks.title;
```

Finally, an XMLListCollection class is basically a helper class for taking your XML or XMLList object and using it in a control.

Take this snippet from `mx.core.Repeater` docs on its `dataProvider` property

```
If you set it to an XML or XMLList, it is converted into an XMLListCollection.
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you very much @Mark Koopman. Its a very good and simple explanation. :)

Answer (score 4):

An XMLListCollection is probably what you want to use.  It has data binding and works well as a datasource in a datagrid.

An XMLListCollection is built from an XMLList. But after you have made an XMLListCollection from your XMLList, you rarely (if ever) use the XMLList again.

I rarely use XML.  I think XML is mostly for backwards compatibility and that you are encouraged to use XMLList and XMLListCollection instead.