# Populate Tree Using xml file

Tags: xml, apache-flex, tree, adobe, mxml

Help,

In mxml I can load an xmlfile into an xmllistcollection at runtime using an httpservice, and then assign that to a list object.

I can also define an xml object menu tree structure in the code and assign it to a tree.

What I can't do is load the xml file at runtime and assign it to a tree.

So I'm trying to load a file:

```
<root>
 <menuitem name="First Main Item">
   <menuitem name = "sub item 1"/>
   <menuitem name = "sub item 2"/>
 </menuitem>
 <menuitem name="First Main Item">
   <menuitem name = "sub item 3"/>
   <menuitem name = "sub item 4"/>
 </menuitem>
</root>
```

into a tree at runtime.

Any clues as to how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a HTTPService to send a request to your URL.
The Tree component uses a List as data provider, so you need to use

```
dataProvider="{myXml.menuitem}"
```

to convert your XML to a List. Don't forget to define a labelField of your tree

```
labelField="@name"
```

Here is the Tree:

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
           minWidth="955" minHeight="600" 
           creationComplete="myService.send()">
<fx:Declarations>
    <s:HTTPService id="myService" url="com/xmltree/tree.xml" resultFormat="e4x" result="onServiceResult(event)"/>
</fx:Declarations>

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;

        [Bindable]private var myXml:XML;

        private function onServiceResult(event:ResultEvent):void
        {
            myXml = event.result as XML;
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:HGroup x="20" y="20">
    <mx:Tree 
        dataProvider="{myXml.menuitem}" 
        labelField="@name"/>
</s:HGroup>

</s:Application>
```

Comment: Thank you!  It works a treat.  I was missing the .menuitem in the line dataProvider="{myXml.menuitem}" and I'm still not sure I understand why this is required.  When I declared the xml in the code I just had dataProvider="{myXml}".  Why is the .menuitem required here?

Comment: I think you need always a list to use it in your tree. The expression "myXml.menuitem" is a transformation XML->XMLList. You could do it after getting an answer from the server as well. Could you post your code where you used a XML declared in your code?

Comment: You can read something about XML->XMLList transformation here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6386312/xml-and-xmllist-and-xmllistcollection-in-flex-3